# Raster to vector conversion with pixel values

Tags: python, raster, gdal, vector

I have one raster file. I want to convert that into vector file. I'm using Python (GDAL) for that. I found some solution. But the issue is after vectoring it is not getting the polygon attribute value. Like I have some pixels with value of 1 & 2. Converted polygons should have those value in attribute. Is there any solution for that? How can I do that?

I've used this code so far:

```
#get raster data source
open_image = gdal.Open("/home/sat/Projects/1259/agri/crop/tiffs/crop.tif")
input_band = open_image.GetRasterBand(1)

#create output data source
output_shp = "/home/sat/Projects/1259/agri/crop/"
shp_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
#create output file name
output_shapefile = shp_driver.CreateDataSource(output_shp + "\\deoria_rasTOvec.shp" )
new_shapefile = output_shapefile.CreateLayer(output_shp, srs = None )

gdal.Polygonize(input_band, None, new_shapefile, -1, [], callback=None)
new_shapefile.SyncToDisk()
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/444011/edit) to include the output of `gdalinfo -stats /home/sat/Projects/1259/agri/crop/tiffs/crop.tif`

Answer (score 3):

You are probably missing creating a field for your output Shapefile. I will assume the field is an integer from your message, and this is how your code ought to look like:

```py
#get raster data source
open_image = gdal.Open("/home/sat/Projects/1259/agri/crop/tiffs/crop.tif")
input_band = open_image.GetRasterBand(1)

#create output data source
output_shp = "/home/sat/Projects/1259/agri/crop/"
shp_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
#create output file name
output_shapefile = shp_driver.CreateDataSource(output_shp + "\\deoria_rasTOvec.shp" )
new_layer = output_shapefile.CreateLayer(output_shp, srs = None)
new_field = ogr.FieldDefn('new_field', ogr.OFTInteger) # Create a new field of type intenger
new_layer.CreateField(new_field) # Add the field to the layer
gdal.Polygonize(input_band, None, new_layer, 
                -1, [], callback=None)

output_shapefile.Destroy()
```

Comment: Like this field created but the values are not updated. everything is null only. I'm totally clueless how we can append the field values with raster pixel values.